# Mongo Search Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-mongo, mongotemplate, spring-mongodb

Following is structure of my mongo document and I want to search all such documents for which ***w*** is true.

***w*** is key of first element in array ***cd***

```html
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55cc9bd9e4b07c05e5812de7"),
    "_class" : "com.test.MyClass",
    "cd" : [ 
        {
            "d" : 54.6199989318847660,
            "w" : "true",
            "x" : "false",
        
        }
    ],
    "sts" : "READ"
}
```

***FYI:***   I am using Spring Mongo Template to connect to DB

Answer (score 0):

You should use dot notation to compare the specific element of the array. If you need the **w** property of the **first** element of **cd** array, it will be like this:

```
db.collectionName.find({"cd.0.w":true})
```

See more at [mondoDB tutorial page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-a-specific-element-of-an-array)